# How to make a relation between data table in data set

Tags: c#

I have one data set `DS1`. In this data set have two data tables: `DT1` and `DT2`
The layout of the data ables looks like this:

DT1 Data:

```
**ID  Name**
   1  Amit
   2  Alok
   3  Munish
```

DT2 Data:

```
**ID  Name**
   2  Alok
   3  Munish
   4  Firoj
```

I want to create a new table that looks like:

```
**ID  Name**
   2  Alok
   3  Munish
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to merge the data tables without duplicates? And would `Firoj` also be included in the resulting table?

Answer (score 2):

The `DataTable` class has a `Merge` method:

```
DataTable DT1;
DataTable DT2;
DT1.Merge(DT2);
```

[DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx)